# Why do my app registers itself as a browser?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I create an app.But the issue is it registers itself as a browser. When on the phone I click any link the options show browser and my app. Why it is like that?

Comment: can you maybe post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You should include enough detail while asking a question otherwise you have to face "closed"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application has registered intent filters for handling intents of the `http` scheme.

There's [an example of building a custom browser on Lars Vogel's blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/02/21/android-intents/), which boils down to:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".BrowserActivitiy"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

If you wish to disable this behavior, remove the `<intent-filter>` tag from your activity.

Answer (score 2):

You should check in your **Android Manifest** the intents filters part, you may have defined an intent filter for browsing

Comment: ok I check it and then turn back to you , thanks